# Using `dplyr` or `purrr` to get means of multiple columns that share a string fragment (e.g. year)

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, purrr

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
df <- 
  data.frame(
    a_1995 = 1:4,
    b_1995 = 11:14,
    a_1996 = 21:24,
    a_1997 = 1:4,
    b_1997 = 51:54,
    a_1998 = 31:34,
    a_1999 = 21:24)
```

For some years, I have multiple measures, therefore. I want to create a new set of columns, which are the averages of the 1 or 2 measurements take for that year. I could do this manually as follows to get the desired output:

```
out <- 
  df %>% 
  mutate(
    avg_1995 = rowMeans(select(., contains("1995"))),
    avg_1996 = rowMeans(select(., contains("1996"))),
    avg_1997 = rowMeans(select(., contains("1997"))),
    avg_1998 = rowMeans(select(., contains("1998"))),
    avg_1999 = rowMeans(select(., contains("1999"))))
```

Is there a way to automate this using `purrr` or `dplyr` functions? (I have hundreds of columns like this.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option could be:

```
map_dfc(.x = as.character(1995:1999), 
        ~ df %>%
         transmute(!!paste("ave", .x, sep = "_") := rowMeans(select(., contains(.x)))))

  ave_1995 ave_1996 ave_1997 ave_1998 ave_1999
1        6       21       26       31       21
2        7       22       27       32       22
3        8       23       28       33       23
4        9       24       29       34       24
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another base R solution using `aggregate`

```
u<-aggregate(.~year,data.frame(year = gsub("\\D+","avg_",names(df)),t(df)),mean)
dfout <- setNames(data.frame(t(u[-1]),row.names = NULL),u$year)
```

such that

```
> dfout
  avg_1995 avg_1996 avg_1997 avg_1998 avg_1999
1        6       21       26       31       21
2        7       22       27       32       22
3        8       23       28       33       23
4        9       24       29       34       24
```

Answer (score 0):

Base R

```
d = data.frame(lapply(split.default(df, gsub("\\D+", "", names(df))), rowMeans), check.names = FALSE)
names(d) = paste0("avg_", names(d))
cbind(df, d)
```

tidyverse

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
    mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
    left_join(df %>%
    mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
    gather(key, val, -rn) %>%
    mutate(year = paste0("avg_", gsub("\\D+", "", key))) %>%
    group_by(rn, year) %>%
    summarise(val = mean(val)) %>%
    spread(year, val),
    by = "rn") %>%
    select(-rn)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with `tidyr` and `dplyr` :

```r
df <- 
    data.frame(
        a_1995 = 1:4,
        b_1995 = 11:14,
        a_1996 = 21:24,
        a_1997 = 1:4,
        b_1997 = 51:54,
        a_1998 = 31:34,
        a_1999 = 21:24)

suppressPackageStartupMessages( library(dplyr) )
suppressPackageStartupMessages( library(tidyr) )

df %>% 
    pivot_longer(data = ., cols = names(.),
             names_to = "type_year"
             ) %>% 
    separate(col = "type_year", into = c("type", "year"), sep = "_") %>% 
    group_by(year) %>% 
    summarise(mean_value = mean(value)) %>% 
    pivot_wider(names_from = year, values_from = mean_value) %>% 
    rename_all(~paste0("avg_", .))
#> # A tibble: 1 x 5
#>   avg_1995 avg_1996 avg_1997 avg_1998 avg_1999
#>      <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1      7.5     22.5     27.5     32.5     22.5
```

Answer (score 0):

additional solution

```
result <- df %>% 
  mutate(n = row_number()) %>% 
  pivot_longer(-n) %>% 
  tidyr::extract(name, "year", "(\\d{4})") %>% 
  group_by(n, year) %>% 
  summarise(value = mean(value, na.rm = T)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(n, names_from = year, values_from = value, names_prefix = "avg_") %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(-n) %>% 
  bind_cols(df, .)
```